# Diesel AsExpression: why Option <-> Nullable needs to be implemented explicitly

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Let's say I have a very simple `Insertable` struct containing a custom struct:

```
#[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Insertable)]
#[table_name = "my_temp_table"]
#[primary_key(id)]
pub struct MyTempTable {
    pub id: i32,
    pub non_optional: MyText,
    pub optional: Option<MyText>,
}

pub struct MyText(pub String);
```

And the corresponding schema:

```
table! {
    my_temp_table (id) {
        id -> Integer, 
        non_optional -> Text,
        optional -> Nullable<Text>,
    }
}
```

I would get an error :

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyText: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> my_cool_file.rs:66:35
   |
66 | #[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Insertable)]
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `MyText`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `diesel::Expression`:
             Box<T>
             migrations_internals::schema::__diesel_schema_migrations::columns::star
             migrations_internals::schema::__diesel_schema_migrations::columns::version
             migrations_internals::schema::__diesel_schema_migrations::columns::run_on
           and 484 others
   = note: required for `MyText` to implement `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Text>`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Insertable` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

It makes sense, I need to implement `AsExpression` for `MyText` :

```
impl AsExpression<Text> for MyText {
    type Expression = AsExprOf<String, Text>;
    fn as_expression(self) -> Self::Expression {
        <String as AsExpression<Text>>::as_expression(self.0)
    }
}

impl<'a> AsExpression<Text> for &'a MyText {
    type Expression = AsExprOf<String, Text>;
    fn as_expression(self) -> Self::Expression {
        <String as AsExpression<Text>>::as_expression(self.0.to_owned())
    }
}
```

but even after doing that  I still have a very similar error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyText: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> my_cool_file.rs:66:35
   |
66 | #[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Insertable)]
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `MyText`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `diesel::Expression`:
             Box<T>
             migrations_internals::schema::__diesel_schema_migrations::columns::star
             migrations_internals::schema::__diesel_schema_migrations::columns::version
             migrations_internals::schema::__diesel_schema_migrations::columns::run_on
           and 484 others
   = note: required for `&'insert MyText` to implement `diesel::Expression`
   = note: required for `&'insert MyText` to implement `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>>`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Insertable` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

This confuses me as I would have expected the `Option<Foo> <-> Nullable<SQLType>` to work out of the box if `Foo <-> SQLType` works but I still need to implement

```
impl AsExpression<Nullable<Text>> for MyText 
impl<'a> AsExpression<Nullable<Text>> for &'a MyText
```

And same for `ToSql` and `FromSql` traits if I need them.

Is it expected that I need to implement the Nullable case explicitly too or should it work out of the box and I missed something?

I am using Diesel 1.4.8.

Comment: This question has several issues, so it's hard to answer it. Try to reduce it to a single question and provide a complete minimal reproducible example including the complete error messages as emitted by rustc. The provided example should also be consistent with your actual code and not mix syntax from diesel 2.0 and 1.4.

Comment: @weiznich 1. you can discard Q1 and only answer Q2. 2. "and not mix syntax from diesel 2.0 and 1.4" What syntax is from 2.0?

Comment: All `#[diesel()]` attributes are diesel 2.0 syntax. Also you still need to update your question to include the complete error message as emitted by the compiler.

Comment: "All #[diesel()] attributes are diesel 2.0 syntax" I did not now that. This could explain why the `#[derive(AsExpression)]` didn't work then (I didn't get any error though). If I look at the [docs for AsExpression for 1.4](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel_derives/derive.AsExpression.html) it's empty so it's not clear to me if it was supported yet. So I removed that part of the question and might ask an independent question then.

Comment: Honestly my question is quite straightforward: "Do I actually need to implement AsExpression for Nullable too?" I honestly don't know if you really think you need the whole error message as I had extracted the interesting parts to avoid noise or you are just being pedantic, but I am assuming good intent and edited it with the full message, even though I don't think it adds anything.

Comment: For diesel issues the complete error message is required as it usually contains important information about the underlying issue. In this case the important part is in the second last line of the error message.

Comment: "In this case the important part is in the second last line of the error message." => so you mean the exact line I provided in my original question?

Comment: You can continue to argue about that, but I generally only answer questions that at least try to provide a more or less complete set of information. Just remember: The main reason this site exists is that others can find helpful questions and answers here. Being helpful for others usually includes the complete error message as that makes it easier to find such things via google. I don't see the point of spending my time to answer questions that are not helpful for others, as my main motivation is mostly to have a public set of answers, and not to answer individual users questions.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is somewhat expected. The [documentation of ToSql](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/serialize/trait.ToSql.html) states:

> Any types which implement this trait should also #[derive(AsExpression)].

This derive would then generate all necessary implementations of `AsExpression` for you.

Now this derives is (as you already noticed) not really documented for diesel 1.4. Given that this diesel version is outdated for more than 2 years I would suggest that you update to diesel 2.x and then work with [the documentation](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.1.x/diesel/expression/derive.AsExpression.html) there. That documentation also contains a full list of impls that are generated.

Comment: I understand that all the types need to implement `AsExpression`. My question is that given I implement `AsExpression<Text> for MyText`, wouldn't diesel be able to handle `impl AsExpression<Nullable<Text>> for MyText` by itself?

Comment: By the way I don't really understand why we need to implement `impl AsExpression<Nullable<Text>> for MyText ` given that the conversion is not done from `MyText -> Nullable<Text>` but `Option<MyText> ->  Nullable<Text>`

Comment: It's not possible to have a generic impl for that, due to conflicting other generic impls. It would confict with `impl<E, ST> AsExpression<ST> for E where E: Expression<SqlType = ST>` (which is required to accept DSL expressions in all positions)